# Google Developer Tools, beta testing an app

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app that already exists on the market, but now when I'm trying to do a beta test my new version of the app ( closed beta-testing ) it gives me a link to become a tester and it says "in a few hours you will get the update for the app". But that never happens.

I've been waiting for that update since yesterday, it's been like 24 hours now since i posted the app for beta testing.

My question is, what is going on? Did i miss something?

I used the current keystore file and signed a new one for the APK i uploaded.

Comment: Try to open the link. It will open the Google Play site and you can see the beta version there.

Comment: I did, but it refers me to the current app on the market and it only says "Open app" / "Remove app".

I have also checked the section with "My apps" -> Beta, but i's empty.

Comment: You can see the apk version name on Google Play Store. Does the link refer you to the same version as the production apk?

Comment: Yes, the link refers me to the production apk.

Comment: Have you tried to add other people for beta testing?

Comment: I've also added my second android phone with it's own gmail account, nothing there..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135359/discussion-between-top-and-robin-ryden).

Answer (score 0):

Play Store will only offer you an update if:

- You have signed up to the beta test
- A beta version is available that has a higher version than the one installed on your device
- You are signed in with the Google account that is part of the beta
  program.
- The beta APK is valid for the device. i.e It has not been excluded because the device lacks a feature defined as required by the manifest

I would check how many Google Accounts are on the device and if the app in question was actually installed from Play Store using the account that is the tester.

[image: device play store]

Comment: I signed up with my gmail that is part of the list for the beta app.
The old versionCode was "24" it's "28" in the new APK now.
I am also signed in with the google account because i got the rights to see the link for becoming a tester.

Comment: The Play Store app will also display "You're a beta tester for this app. Awesome!" in the listing if you are signed up properly. This does not seem to appear on the web site version.